# how to start each function from index 1 to post json objects in different div in html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I have this json data [image: json data]

somehow i displayed this part of data in html [image: personal details]

and want to display this part of data

[image: books detail]

into div in html but i am unable to display it using for loop and don't to how to start each function from index 1 as index 0 in personal details data.

here is my code

```js
var url = "http://localhost/ReadExchange/api.php";
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      if (data) {
        alert("hey got the data" + JSON.stringify(data));
        var arr = data.length;

        //$.each(data, function(i,element) {
        var element = data[0];
        $("#postjson").append(
          '<div id="' + element.id + '">' + '<p>' + 'FirstName:' + element.FirstName + '<br/>'

          + 'MiddleName:' + element.MiddleName + '<br/>' + 'LastName:' + element.LastName + '<br/>' + 'Gender:' + element.Gender + '<br/>' + 'Location:' + element.Location + '<br/>' + 'Email:' + element.Email + '<br/>' + 'Mobile:' + element.Mobile + '<br/>' + '</p>' + '</div>'
        );

        for (var i = 1; i < arr; i++) {
          $("#postjson").append(
            '<div id="">' + '<p>' + 'BookTitle:' + data[i].data.BookTitle + '<br/>' + 'BookGenre:' + data[i].data.BookGenre + '<br/>' + 'BookWriter:' + data[i].data.BookWriter + '<br/>' + 'Gender:' + data[i].data.BookDescription + '<br/>'

            + '</p>' + '</div>'
          );
        }

      } else {
        return;
      }
```

Comment: try to reformat your question content to make it more readable

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.splice()`

```
data.splice(0, 1);
```

then iterate `data` array at `for` loop, with `i` set to `0`

```js
var data = [{abc:123}, {def:456}];

data.splice(0, 1);

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(data))
}
```